# How do I execute different Testcases with different structure through NodeJS and Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

How do I execute different Testcases with different structure through **`NodeJS` and `Mocha`**.

Moving forward I intend to integrate **`Selenium`** + **`NodeJS`** + **`Mocha`**

I have just started to explore NodeJS with Mocha and need some help.

1. Installed `node.js`:

   ```
   C:\Users\AtechM_03>node -v
   v6.11.2
   ```
2. Installed `npm`:

   ```
   C:\Users\AtechM_03>npm -v
   3.10.10
   ```
3. Configured `nodeclipse` as per this [link](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/) and my Project structure looks like:

[image]

4. Installed `Mocha` at the default location (through command-line) as per [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/selenium-nodejs-and-mocha).

   ```
   C:\Users\AtechM_03>npm install -g mocha
   C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\npm\mocha -> C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\npnode_modules\mocha\bin\mocha
   C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\npm\_mocha -> C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\n\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha
   C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\npm
   `-- mocha@3.5.3
   ```
5. Followed [this link](https://codeburst.io/how-to-test-javascript-with-mocha-the-basics-80132324752e) to write a program in NodeJS integrating Mocha.
6. Created a directory named `test` with in `NodeProject` space.
7. Within `test` folder created a file named `test.js`
8. Executed `npm init` to interactively create a `package.json` file.

   ```
       C:\Users\AtechM_03>cd C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject

       C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject>npm init
       This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
       It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

       See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
       and exactly what they do.

       Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
       save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

       Press ^C at any time to quit.
       name: (NodeProject) test
       version: (1.0.0) 1.0.0
       description: test123
       entry point: (index.js) test.js
       test command: (mocha) mocha
       git repository:
       keywords:
       author: debanjan
       license: (ISC)
       About to write to C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject\package.json:

       {
         "name": "test",
         "version": "1.0.0",
         "description": "test123",
         "main": "test.js",
         "directories": {
           "test": "test"
         },
         "dependencies": {
           "g": "^2.0.1",
           "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0"
         },
         "devDependencies": {
           "mocha": "^3.5.3"
         },
         "scripts": {
           "test": "mocha"
         },
         "author": "debanjan",
         "license": "ISC"
       }


       Is this ok? (yes)

   C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject>
   ```
9. `package.json` got generated within the Project Scope i.e. under `C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject` as follows:

   ```
       {
         "name": "test",
         "version": "1.0.0",
         "description": "test123",
         "main": "test.js",
         "directories": {
           "test": "test"
         },
         "dependencies": {
           "g": "^2.0.1",
           "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0"
         },
         "devDependencies": {
           "mocha": "^3.5.3"
         },
         "scripts": {
           "test": "mocha"
         },
         "author": "debanjan",
         "license": "ISC"
       }
   ```
10. Added code to `test.js` as follows:

    ```
            // Require the built in 'assertion' library
            var assert = require('assert');
            // Create a group of tests about Arrays
            describe('Array', function() {
              // Within our Array group, Create a group of tests for indexOf
              describe('#indexOf()', function() {
                // A string explanation of what we're testing
                it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
                  // Our actual test: -1 should equal indexOf(...)
                  assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
                });
              });

            //Create a test suite (group) called Math
              describe('Math', function() {
                  // Test One: A string explanation of what we're testing
                  it('should test if 3*3 = 9', function(){
                // Our actual test: 3*3 SHOULD EQUAL 9
                assert.equal(9, 3*3);
                  });
                  // Test Two: A string explanation of what we're testing
                  it('should test if (3-4)*8 = -8', function(){
                // Our actual test: (3-4)*8 SHOULD EQUAL -8
                assert.equal(-8, (3-4)*8);
                  });
              });

            });
    ```
11. Executed `npm test` from project space which runs successfully:

    ```
            C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject>npm test

            > temperature@1.0.0 test C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject
            > mocha



              Array
                #indexOf()
                  v should return -1 when the value is not present
                Math
                  v should test if 3*3 = 9
                  v should test if (3-4)*8 = -8


              3 passing (18ms)
    ```
12. Followed [this link](https://codeburst.io/how-to-test-javascript-with-mocha-part-2-2d83fcb6101a) to write a second program in NodeJS integrating Mocha.
13. Created a separate directory named `temperature` with in `NodeProject` space.
14. In the `temperature` directory created a file named `app.js` and a folder name `test`
15. Within the test folder, created a file named `test.js`
16. Moved the previous `package.json` to a sub-directory and executed `npm init` to interactively create a new `package.json` file again.

    ```
            C:\Users\AtechM_03>cd C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject

            C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject>npm init
            This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
            It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

            See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
            and exactly what they do.

            Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
            save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

            Press ^C at any time to quit.
            name: (NodeProject) temperature
            version: (1.0.0) 1.0.0
            description: temp
            entry point: (index.js) app.js
            test command: (mocha) mocha
            git repository:
            keywords:
            author: debanjanb
            license: (ISC)
            About to write to C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject\package.json:

            {
              "name": "temperature",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "description": "temp",
              "main": "app.js",
              "directories": {
                "test": "test"
              },
              "dependencies": {
                "g": "^2.0.1",
                "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "mocha": "^3.5.3"
              },
              "scripts": {
                "test": "mocha"
              },
              "author": "debanjanb",
              "license": "ISC"
            }


        Is this ok? (yes)
    ```
17. New `package.json` gets created as follows:

    ```
            {
              "name": "temperature",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "description": "temp",
              "main": "app.js",
              "directories": {
                "test": "test"
              },
              "dependencies": {
                "g": "^2.0.1",
                "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "mocha": "^3.5.3"
              },
              "scripts": {
                "test": "mocha"
              },
              "author": "debanjanb",
              "license": "ISC"
            }
    ```
18. The current `temperature` Testcase looks like:

[image]

19. Tried to execute this second program through `npm test` from the Project space but it still executes the first program as follows:

    ```
        C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject>npm test

        > temperature@1.0.0 test C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\NodeProject
        > mocha



          Array
            #indexOf()
              v should return -1 when the value is not present
            Math
              v should test if 3*3 = 9
              v should test if (3-4)*8 = -8


          3 passing (18ms)
    ```

### Question :

I know my second program `app.js` is incomplete and executing it will show error (e.g. `0 passing (20ms)`) but my `app.js` is not getting invoked at all.

Can someone please guide/suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

Any suggestion/guide/pointer will be helpful.

### Update:

As of now my current code for `app.js` is incomplete and contains the following code:

```
        cToF = function(celsius) {
          if(!Number.isInteger(celsius)) return undefined;
          return celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        }

        fToC = function(fahrenheit) {
          if(!Number.isInteger(fahrenheit)) return undefined;
          return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        }
```

As per [this website](https://codeburst.io/how-to-test-javascript-with-mocha-part-2-2d83fcb6101a) I am following I expect an error as `0 passing (20ms)`

Comment: can you please show what content your app.js has?

Comment: @HarshPatel Updated question as per your comments.

Comment: There is no describe or it methods/function written in your app.js file. So, it won't show any output to the console. but It will execute for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got quite the long description but the thing I extracted from it is that you have essentially a structure like this:

```
NodeProject
├── temperature
│   └── test
└── test
```

Then you go into `NodeProject` and run Mocha. By default Mocha will look only for `test` in the same directory where it is invoked. So it won't look for `temperature/test`. If you want Mocha to run the tests in `temperature/test` you have to tell Mocha explicitly. For instance, this would work:

```
mocha test temperature/test
```

I'll address a common misconception here because I often see people make the mistake: merely using the `--recursive` flag is not enough. If you use this flag, then *after* Mocha has identified directories in which to find tests, it will look in them recursively. However, it does not change how Mocha identifies directories in which to find tests. Specifically, if you use `mocha --recursive`, it will still only look in `test`, and it will look in subdirectories of `test`. This won't make it look in `temperature/test`. If you do have subdirectories in `test` and `temperature/test`, you could do:

```
mocha --recursive test temperature/test
```